# How to implement a C program that display five longest words from a text file?

Tags: c, visual-studio

The text file has 225000 words. In the following sequence:

```
d
d
da
dog
dover
Denmark
lovethislifetoenjoy
beautifully
travelllerwise
lovethislifetoenjoy
alaskabluewheals
oceanisbluee
lovethislifetoenjoyfuntravel
basketball
lovethislifetoenjoyfuntravel
fashion
londonis
```

..

So the program should print the followings:

---

lovethislifetoenjoyfuntravel

travelllerwise

alaskabluewheals

oceanisbluee

lovethislifetoenjoyfuntravel

---

So far I coded this

```
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    errno_t err;
    char current_Word[1024];
    char longest_word[1024];
    int ct=0;
    char longWordList = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 10);

        if ((err = fopen_s(&fp, "dictionary.txt", "r")) != 0) 
    {
        printf("Cannot open file.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    memset(longest_word, '\0', sizeof(longest_word));
    while(fscanf_s(fp, "%s", current_Word, _countof(current_Word))!= EOF)
    {
           if (ct == 0)
           {
           strcpy(longest_word, current_Word);
       }

       if (strlen(current_Word) > strlen(longest_word))
       {
        strcpy(longest_word, current_Word);
       }
       ct++;

    }
    /* print */
    printf("\nThe longest word is\n");
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", longest_word);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

The program only print this -> lovethislifetoenjoyfuntravel

**How I do keep track of all the longest words in a storage and then compare those words from the storage area with the word just read from input file?**

If multiple words tied with the 5th longest word then end the program and print the final storage.

**How to end the program when I find few tied with the 5th word that is the storage?**

I do write code in Java and Python but this is something I need to completed for my department initiative.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 community edition for this project.

Your assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: As for your problem, a good start to solve your problem would be to have space for five strings?

Comment: This programm cannot work, and compile with many severe warning (maybe not compile at all) `char longWordList = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 10)`

Comment: As you print the 5 longest words, you don't print lovethislifetoenjoy. Why?

Comment: I would probably just brute-force it: load the entire file into memory, count the number of lines while building an array of line-pointers, then `qsort()` the array of pointers and finally print the first five entries. Would likely run in milliseconds assuming the input isn't overly massive, and be quite simple to understand and reason about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should display the five longest words.
In addition it will also print additional words, which their sizes are the same as the shortest word of the five longest words in the file:

```
#define WORD_MAX_SIZE           (50)
#define LONGEST_WORDS_COUNT     (5)

int main()
{
    char    sCurWord[WORD_MAX_SIZE+1];
    char    arrLongestWords[LONGEST_WORDS_COUNT][WORD_MAX_SIZE+1];
    int     iShortestWordIndex = 0;
    FILE*   fp;

    memset( arrLongestWords, 0, sizeof(arrLongestWords));

    if( 0 != fopen_s(&fp, "C:\\Temp\\BlaBla.txt", "r"))
    {
        printf("Cannot open file.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    while( fscanf_s( fp, "%1023s ", sCurWord, WORD_MAX_SIZE) == 1)
    {
        if( strlen(arrLongestWords[iShortestWordIndex]) < strlen(sCurWord))
            strcpy_s( arrLongestWords[iShortestWordIndex], WORD_MAX_SIZE, sCurWord);

        //  Re-calculate shortest word index:
        iShortestWordIndex    = 0;
        for( int i=1; i<LONGEST_WORDS_COUNT; i++)
        {
            if( strlen( arrLongestWords[i]) < strlen( arrLongestWords[iShortestWordIndex]))
            {
                iShortestWordIndex = i;
            }
        }
    }

    /* print */
    printf("\n%d longest words are:\n", LONGEST_WORDS_COUNT);
    for( int i=1; i<LONGEST_WORDS_COUNT; i++)
    {
        ::printf( "\t%s\r\n", arrLongestWords[i]);
    }

    ::printf( "\r\nOther words in the file, which their length are the same as the %dth largest word:\r\n", LONGEST_WORDS_COUNT);
    //  Move file-pointer back, to the beginning of the file:
    rewind(fp);
    //  Now go over file once more to find all words, which their sizes are the
    //  same as the shortest word:
    while( fscanf_s( fp, "%1023s ", sCurWord, WORD_MAX_SIZE) == 1)
    {
        if( strlen(arrLongestWords[iShortestWordIndex]) == strlen(sCurWord))
            ::printf( "\t%s\r\n", sCurWord);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi John, Thanks a lot, I appreciated it very much.

Comment: Please advice what would be the best approach to print all the words those are the same length of arrLongestWords at index 4?

Comment: Hi @Josh S, just to clarify your question: do you mean to print all words from file whos size is as long as item[4]? If so I assume we could read whole file once more and search for words of this size (?) Thanks, John

Comment: Hi John, Thank you. Yes that's right. So if item[4] contain this "lovethislifetoenjoyfuntravel" string. Then all other strings from the files those matches the length of this string needs to print out.

Comment: Hi @JoshS, I updated the code to print also other words in the file, which their sizes are the same as the shortest word of the five longest word. I think this is what you meant. If you prefer to print words of size equivalent to that of item[4] please replace 'arrLongestWords[iShortestWordIndex]' at the bottom with 'arrLongestWords[LONGEST_WORDS_COUNT-1]'. If you find my answer helpful please do mark it as accepted so I can gain points. Thanks, John

Comment: Hi John, Thank you for your help and support, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No real need for malloc, that is badly defined here.

you should keep a multi-dimensional array for the longest words like this:

```
char longest_word[5][1024];
```

also add a variable shortest_long_word_len:

```
int shortest_long_word_len = 0;
int shortest_long_word_location = 0;
```

Then as you test for current_Word, check its len vs. shortest_long_word_len. If longer, then strcpy the new word to the array in shortest_long_word_location

```
strcpy(longest_word[shortest_long_word_location], current_Word);
```

After that just recalculate shortest_long_word_len and shortest_long_word_location

Comment: Hi Shlomi, Thank you for your help.